# Attempting to get the name of an MSI installer file from an executable run from the installer

Tags: c#, windows-installer

We have an .msi installer that requires we run a prerequisite app written in C# before finishing the install.

That app needs to be given some values from the filename of the .msi

The .msi runs the file with this command:

```
<CustomAction Id="EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait" FileKey="Agent_Manager.exe" ExeCommand="--firstinstall" />
```

Inside of our executable, we need to be able to retrieve the filename of the .msi

```
var myId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
var query = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", myId);
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
var results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();
results.MoveNext();
var queryObj = results.Current;
var parentId = (uint)queryObj["ParentProcessId"];
var parent = Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId);
return parent.ProcessName;
```

I thought this would be the solution, but this returns "msiexec"

Is there a way for me to get the file name?

Comment: Could you please motivate why you are needing this? It is a bit unusual.

Comment: because we only have control of the .msi filename.

Answer (score 0):

We found an even better solution. When you run an installer, it's name is placed in the Registry at CurrentUser\MicrosoftInstaller\Products<ProductID>\SourcrList.